node.js LTS releases - Defender365 recommendation for security updates
Microsoft Defender365 is recommending updating to the latest release of node.js due to known security exploits, so can a developer (any) let me know the ideas of LTS releases and how they are to be patched for security updates?
I assume like Linux distros, there are security updates for LTS versions of these distros, but does the node.js LTS release automatically/prompt to do the same?
Does the developer of the application that packaged/installed node.js update/patch the vulnerable components of node.js? All-in-all, can I ignore Microsoft Defedner365's recommendation to update if I have deployed node.js LTS?
Many thanks,
Trooper
Wanting to find out if I need to update from node.js 'v20.18' LTS, to resolved security exploits within node.js.


the ideas of LTS

LTS, or "Long Term Support" are the even-numbered versions of Node.js that come out every April-ish. "LTS status" means that these even versions of Node will get critical updates for about 30 months from its release. This usually equates to:

6 months of "it's the Current version of node"
then 2 years of "it's not current, but they'll release security updates".


how they are to be patched for security updates

The same way your computer does: by someone or something specifically installing updates.

Does the developer of the application that packaged/installed node.js update/patch the vulnerable components of node.js? All-in-all, can I ignore Microsoft Defedner365's recommendation to update if I have deployed node.js LTS?

No, you shouldn't ignore it, and yes, you have to update your version. You don't have to update "components" though. Node is a binary, so you just need to swap out the installation for a newer one. This is usually very straightforward. If you stay within the same "major" (20.0.0 -> 20.18.0), it should be backward compatible, and even between major versions, it mostly is.

update from node.js 'v20.18' LTS

You didn't post the message it gave you, but I assume it's telling you to upgrade TO v20.18 and not FROM it. 20.18.0 was released about 3 weeks ago, and it is the latest version of Node.js.

Thank you. I was anticipating such a valued response from this community as it has great people such as yourself, alas, this has helped me understand a lot more about the node.js updating process.
